# Flask WebServer To Test Login

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I wrote a small webserver using flask and python to test the response of a program. When the user try to login the program sends to the server a xml file with the data and if everything works, returns a xml file and a cookie if something goes wrong it returns a xml file with the error.

I am new on all this and would like to get some opinion on what I did and maybe how I could improve.

```
import uuid
import hashlib
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, redirect
import xmltodict
from xml.etree import ElementTree as xml


Server = Flask(__name__)

_email = 'email@email.com' #email to be sent via xml to test
_password = 'keineahnung'  #password to be sent via xml to test



#if one of the values above does not match the values sent through the xml 
#file
#the method LoginError will be called and the xml file loginError will be 
#sent as response

@Server.route('/', methods=['GET']) 
# This is a test I wanted to implement to check via browser if I can 
#redirect the user to the login page

def api_root():   

    for name in request.cookies: 

    #search if the cookie with the user email already exists

    value = request.cookies.get('sessionid')
    if  value ==  hashlib.md5(_email.encode('utf')).hexdigest():
        print('Logged')

        return 'Welcome back, '+_email

return redirect('/login', code=302)

@Server.route('/login', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def Login(): 

if request.method == 'GET': 
#Test the cookie session via browser
    return LoginPassed(_email) 
#Pass automatically the right email so the cookie can be created
else:

    xmlFile = xmltodict.parse(request.data) #Converts the xml to json dict
    user = xmlFile['LOGIN']['BENUTZER']
    password = xmlFile['LOGIN']['PASSWORT']

for name in request.cookies: 
#search if the cookie with the user email already exists

    value = request.cookies.get('sessionid')
    if  value ==  hashlib.md5(user.encode('utf')).hexdigest():
        print('Logged')
        redirect('/loginPassed.xml', code=302)
        return 'Welcome back, '+user
    return LoginError()

#if a post request is made the login file is decoded into a json dictionary
#the user email and password sent through the file are checked against the 
_email and _password constant values

if request.method == 'POST':   
    if user == _email: 
        if password == _password: 
            return LoginPassed(user)     
    return LoginError()


#if email or password does not match this function will be called
# a loginError.xml will be returned

@Server.route('/loginError.xml', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def LoginError():  
    print('Login Failed')  
    redirect('/loginError.xml', code=302)
    response = make_response(open('LoginError.xml').read())
    response.headers["Content-type"] = "text/xml"
    return response

#If login data is correct the app.route delivers the loginPassed.xml file
# and creates a new session_id and cookie for the user

@Server.route('/loginPassed.xml', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def LoginPassed(user):
    print('Loged w success')
    _cookieExpireOn = 60 #cookie expires in 60 seconds
    sessionid = hashlib.md5(user.encode('utf')).hexdigest() 
    #generates the session id for the cookie   
    response = make_response(open('LoginPassed.xml').read())

    response.headers["SESSION"] = sessionid 
    #includes the session on the header
    response.set_cookie('sessionid', sessionid, path= '/login', 
    max_age=_cookieExpireOn, secure=False, httponly=True) 
    #creates the session cookie using email
    return response    

#initializes the app
if __name__ == '__main__':

Server.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

## This doesn't need to work via webbrowser

P.S:Thanks for the critics and suggestions to improve. I am trying to learn software development and it is really important for me all that help with get here from all of you.